# HTMLUnit not waiting for javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, htmlunit

I'm trying to get content of a div that is generated after all javascript is loaded, but it doesn't matter what I do, it seems to ignore javascript and just returns the page in it's first "version".

I've already searched for all questions about this problem in stackoverflow, but any answer worked out..

Here is my code:

```
    WebClient webClient = null;

    HtmlPage page = null;

    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    try {
        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("myUrl"));

        page = webClient.getPage(request);

        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        List<DomElement> divs = page.getElementsByTagName("div");   

        while(divs.size() <= 46){
            synchronized (page) {
                page.wait(2000); //wait
                    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
                    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
                }
            divs = page.getElementsByTagName("div");
        }

        String content = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();                

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation I encountered not too long ago, I found that simply putting the current thread to sleep for a couple of seconds allowed the remote JavaScript to finish running.  Here's how I have the web client configured:

```
private WebClient getConfiguredWebClient () {
    WebClient aClient = null;
    switch (Configuration.getString("AdMonitor.browser")) {
        case "chrome" :
            aClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            break;
        case "firefox" :
            aClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
            break;
        case "ie" :
            aClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);
            break;
        case "edge" :
            aClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.EDGE);
            break;
        default :
            LOGGER.warn("Browser specified in configuration file (" + Configuration.getString("Monitor.browser") + ") is unsupported - defaulting to \"BEST_SUPPORTED\" . . .");
            aClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
    }
    aClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3 * 1000); // Experimental API: May be changed in next release and may not yet work perfectly!
    aClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    aClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    aClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    LOGGER.info(new StringBuilder(64).append("Browser in use: ").append(aClient.getBrowserVersion()));
    return aClient;
}
```

And here is how I got the page in question to finish loading:

```
private HtmlPage getNextPage(WebClient pClient) throws IOException {
    HtmlPage apagLanding = pClient.getPage(new java.net.URL(LANDING_PAGE_URL));
    HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor) apagLanding.getElementById("all");
    HtmlPage apagAllAds = anchor.click();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Pausing for JavaScript execution to return page . . .");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 2);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.info("InterruptedException encountered (non-critical condition) . . .", e);
    }
    return apagAllAds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the code i use for [Wetator](http://www.wetator.org) if you like.
Check [HtmlUnitBrowser.java](https://wetator.repositoryhosting.com/trac/wetator_wetator/browser/trunk/wetator/src/org/wetator/backend/htmlunit/HtmlUnitBrowser.java); starting at method waitForImmediateJobs() or assertContentInTimeFrame().